# How can I animate a submit button to cover the field and display a "Success" message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a designer working along side a developer and I'm trying to help him recreate one of the design elements I created. On our website, we have a section to subscribe to our newsletter. The way I have this envisioned is so that after the user enters their email and clicks submit, the submit button will expand to cover the field and will display a "Success!" message.

How can I go about making this happen? Thanks in advance!

Comment: okay, nice thought. have you tried anything to achieve this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Are you using ajax to submit?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this solves.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzu9vLgc/).

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $(this).val("Success!")
    $(this).animate({
        marginLeft: '-180px',
        width:"220px"
    });
});

<input type="email" id="field"><input style="width:auto;" type="button" value="Subscribe" id="btn">
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd like to see something like this:

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $(this).val("Success!")
    $(this).animate({
        marginLeft: '-110px',
        width:"140px"
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="width:100px" id="field"><input style="width:30px;font-size:25px;" type="button" value="ok" id="btn">
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ymeen0sb/6/)**

This should give a you a start:

```
$(".formFill button").click(function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    var width=$this.outerWidth();
    var inputWidth=$this.siblings("input").outerWidth();

    $this.attr("disabled",true);
    $this.text("Subscribing...");

    $this.animate({
        width:width+inputWidth,
        "margin-left":-inputWidth-4
    });

    //Imitate an ajax post with setTimeout
    setTimeout(function(){
        //succeed
        $this.text("Success!");

        setTimeout(function(){
            //return to normal
            $this.attr("style","");
            $this.removeAttr("disabled");
            $this.text("Subscribe");
        },2000);
    },3000);

});
```